# Pytest hooks are causing tests to be run multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, hook, pytest

I successfully implemented a **pytest hook**, however, now all tests are being run multiple times.

In my root folder I added the following code to `conftest.py` in order to activate the hooks:

```
def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    if report.passed:
        letter = "."
        longrep = ' \u2714 '
    elif report.skipped:
        letter = "s"
        longrep = ' \u27A5 '
    elif report.failed:
        letter = "F"
        longrep = ' \u2717 '
        if report.when != "call":
            letter = "f"
    return report.outcome, letter, report.outcome.upper() + longrep
```

When I remove the hook, each test runs once.

**How can I cause the tests to run once while using the hook?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the `pytest_report_teststatus` hook is called multiple times during the testing process, *(i.e. teardown, call, setup)*.

I added a conditional statement to the beginning of the block to detect when the **hook** was called and only returned values once.

```
def pytest_report_teststatus(report):
    if report.when == 'call': # <-- Added this line
        if report.passed:
            letter = '.'
            longrep = ' \u2714 '
        elif report.skipped:
            letter = 's'
            longrep = ' \u27A5 '
        elif report.failed:
            letter = 'F'
            longrep = ' \u2717 '
        return report.outcome, letter, report.outcome.upper() + longrep
```

Adding `if report.when == 'call'` solved the issue.